# Please indentify this pepper plant

Tags: plant-recommendations, peppers

[image][image]

Hello guys,

I've actually got this pepper plant from my local "bazaar" or market and its been really bothering me as I don't know the variety. Anyone of you ever encountered this? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that such plant has not variety. I have seen many varieties and hybrids similar to your plant. Note: check under the leaves: it seems that leaves are ate by some insects.

Answer (score 1):

These are usually sold simply as 'ornamental pepper' and are varieties of *Capsicum annuum*; this one might be the variety 'Holiday Cheer'.  They are commonly available at this time of year, because now is when they start to produce the decorative fruits. You can eat the fruits if you want, though its not always wise to do so - not only are they very hot indeed, because they're usually sold as decorative,temporary houseplants, they may have been sprayed with substances which make them unhealthy to consume.

With the right care, it should provide a good display for about 8 weeks - they need warm temperatures with, if possible, exposure to sunlight during the day (not outdoors). Further care instructions here https://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/ornamental-chili-pepper.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I've been looking around and these do appear to be the "Holiday Cheer" variety. With regards to the climate, I'm located in the tropics and peppers do very well in my region.